# Problem configuring my first Stripes project

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml, stripes

apparently i'm having some technical problem configuring Stripes.

I use Eclipse ganymede and when i try to run my project from the main project or from the jsp i get a 404 error from Tomcat.

This is the structure of my project:

```
Web-content>Web-inf>lib>....jstl, commons.logging and stripes jars
Web-content>Web-inf>classes>StripesResources.properties
Web-content>Web-inf>classes>stripesbook>action>StripesTime.java
                                               (extends ActionBean)
Web-content>Web-inf>jsp>stripesTime.jsp
Web-content>Web-inf>lib>web.xml....which looks as follows:
```

web.xml:
      Stripes

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Stripes Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
      <param-value>stripesbook.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>StripesTime.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Apparently, jars are loaded correctly, the packages are in the right places "the stripes tutorial i'm following inserts the packages as folders under the web-inf rather then under the Java-Resources:src"
I cant get why, even if i run the jsp file independently, tomcat wont find it.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: I assume you not have `StripesTime.java` but `StripesTime.class` at: `/WEB-INF/classes/stripesbook/action/` (please also note upper case for WEB-INF and the location of the web.xml is directly in /WEB-INF).

Comment: Hi KDeveloper, i had indeed StripesTime.java, i now changed it into StripesTimeActionBean.class  but nothing yet, still trying

Comment: Did I see a typo?  Is it stripesTime.jsp or StripesTime.jsp (the former starts with lowercase 's', the latter with uppercase 'S')

Comment: Agreed w/ Zefi - if the 404 is coming from tomcat, at least that is working.  Try going into the manager app (depending if you have it installed and configured) at localhost:8080/manager/html/list and make sure your app is in there and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripes framework expects the names of action bean classes to end on either Action or Bean. Other class names are ignored, unless you configure Stripes to recognize them (see: [NameBasedActionResolver](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/controller/NameBasedActionResolver.html)).

Thus if you change the name of the **StripesTime** class to **StripesTimeAction** it will be recognized by Stripes and mapped to the URL: "/StripesTime.action".

Please see also: [Stripes URL Bindings and event names](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Use+Defaults+More)

Comment: Done, but still, Tomcat6.0 gives me a 404

Comment: Did you put your project in the ROOT context? If not you should prefix your URL's with the context name (same as subdirectory name in webapps folder).

Comment: i have imported the exact same project into another IDE and now it works, strange, i will report it as bug to the support desk of the ide i was previously using. may i ask you something Kdeveloper, in which folder do you insert the StripesResources.properties file? can you please advise the path? and also "if i dont ask too much" how can you test its functionality? thx

Comment: Like most property files the StripesResources.properties should be placed in the root directory of you class path. For example: WEB-INF/classes. See the Stripes documentation for details: http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Localization